# Highcharts jquery syntaxt in IE 8 not working

Tags: highcharts

When using the jquery syntax $('#container').highcharts(...) and I later want to get a reference to the chart I get an error in IE 8. Example:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });

    $('#container').highcharts().showLoading();
```

The final line fails in IE 8 (works in IE 10 + chrome etc) using version 3.0.1 og highcharts and 1.9.1 of jquery. Is this not the recommended way?

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506)
Timestamp: Tue, 30 Apr 2013 08:07:37 UTC

Message: 'highcharts()' is null or not an object
Line: 66
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mala/highcharts.html

Comment: Which version of IE8 do you have? Because in my: 8.0.6001.18702 works properly and error doesn't appear.

Comment: Same version on Vista Ultimate 32-bit OS. Medium-high security on internet zone and Medium privacy settings. Protected mode is on. Are you using the link: http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mala/highcharts.html

Comment: Yes I've tested this link

Comment: I'm getting the same error testing from browser shots: http://browsershots.org/screenshots/62fe5efffe3596cd42970682ca6113e1

Comment: I just got the same issue.